# Is there any way I can measure the runtime of a program in DOS?

Tags: command-line, time, ms-dos, freedos, profiling

I just want to measure the time it takes a program to go from start to finish.

In UNIX - I can use the `time` command. Is there any way to do this in a MS DOS or FreeDOS?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 4):

There is not. But you can emulate something like with commands:

```
echo.|time
your_command
echo.|time
```

and calculate the difference between two times

One very sample C program like this can help you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
time_t a, b;
a=time(NULL);
system(argv[1]);
b=time(NULL);
printf("%d\n", b-a);
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Is there perhaps a TSR 3rd party tool that can do this very accurately?

Comment: @Coder, I am not aware of such tool

Comment: Cygwin doesn't run in pure DOS.

Comment: @Coder, correct. I realize it and remove my comment :)

Comment: @coder, if you have dev tools you can try with simple C program, using function `time()`

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea.

Comment: @Coder, added one fast and very dirty code in C

Comment: Thanks. I'm already writing a better version.

Comment: PC's time measurements has historically not been very accurate, at some time (originally?) the time resolution was; add a (clock) "tick" 17.2 times per second (average).

Comment: `$ man 7 time` gives the overview, `$ man 7 time | less -p resolution` more detail on "high res" timing.

Comment: @Hannu, here we talk about DOS, not UNIX/Linux

Comment: And I talk about the limitations of the hardware, which is valid regardless of the OS. As reflected by the Linux man page. You may freely add similar resources on the Microsoft OS:es.

Comment: @Hannu, in time of DOS there was some limitations. But now you can have (in some products) time with microseconds. Check Oracle RDBMS

Comment: As reflected by the man page.

Answer (score 1):

Use [4DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS) [shell](https://www.4dos.info/v4dos.htm) instead

> 4DOS is a command interpreter similar to [Command](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Command), but contains extensions such as the ability to scroll back through previous commands, pop-up help, and other useful features. 4DOS was written by Rex Conn and Tom Rawson, both of JP Software.
>
> http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/4DOS

It's the most famous [alternative shell](https://superuser.com/a/926601/241386) that's vastly superior to COMMAND.COM and has a `TIMER` command for your purpose

> The `TIMER` command lets you time events. The following line also shows 4DOS's ability to accept multiple commands on one line, separated by a caret [`^`]. It starts the timer, runs the *TOUR2.BTM* file to create the three demonstration files, deletes the three files, and then stops the timer and displays the time the whole operation took. Enter this command to time the entire sequence on your computer:
>
> ```
> c:\4dos> timer ^ tour2 ^ del filel file2 file3 ^ timer
> Timer 1 on: 11:10:01
>
> Please wait ...
>
> File creation completed
> Deleting c:\4dos\file1
> Deleting c:\4dos\file2
> Deleting c:\4dos\file3
>      3 file(s) deleted
> Timer 1 off: 11:10:06 elapsed: 0:00:05.11
> ```
>
> [jpsoftware :: 4DOS Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_jpsoftware_65101374)
> [page 37 -  Chapter 3 / A guided tour of 4DOS # Other commands] — [Text transcription](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_jpsoftware_65101374/4DOS_Reference_Manual_djvu.txt) for easy searching, but slightly incorrect due to OCR
> ([Alternative link](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/jpsoftware/4DOS_Reference_Manual.pdf))

In fact [4DOS](https://www.4dos.info/4links.htm) is the predecessor of [Take Command / TCC shell in Windows](https://jpsoft.com/products/take-command.html) which also has the [`TIMER` command](https://jpsoft.com/help/timer.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a program called `RUNTIME.EXE` on the FreeDOS 1.3 Bonus CD in the package `RUNTIME.ZIP`. This allows to measure the time it takes a program to run. It's quite similar to unix's time command.